# How does one find subalgebras using the Dynkin diagram of a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams, kac-moody-algebras

The following is taken from [these lecture notes](https://people.phys.ethz.ch/%7Enbeisert/lectures/Sym-20FS-Notes.pdf) on page 8.16:

> [...] $\mathfrak{so}(p+q)$ has as subalgebras $\mathfrak{so}(p)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(q)$ as well as their direct sum $\mathfrak{so}(p)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(q)$. How can this be seen from the Dynkin diagrams?  Suppose $p,q >2$ are even, then the relevant Dynkin diagrams are all of the form:[image]

> By eliminating some nodes one can obtain $\mathfrak{so}(p)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(q)$, but not their direct sum.  However, the direct sum is contained in the affine Dynkin diagram of $\hat{\mathfrak{d}}_{\frac{p+q}{2}}$:
> [image]

> This trick also works if one of $p,q$ is even and the other one is odd:
> [image]

> If both $p,q$ are odd, however, the subalgebra $\mathfrak{so}(p)\oplus \mathfrak{so}(q)$ has lower rank than $\mathfrak{so}(p+q)$ and it cannot be obtained in this way.  Here, the relevant Dynkin diagram is the twisted affine $\mathfrak{so}(p+q)^{(2)}$:
> [image]

### Question

As I understand these statements, one should in principle be able to read off some subalgebras of a given simple Lie algebra directly from the Dynkin diagram of the affine algebra. Unfortunately, I don't really understand the here described technique. It seems that one has just to "eliminate some nodes" to get the result, but I don't really see if there are additional restrictions, or if I can just remove any node and get a valid subalgebra. Could someone maybe elaborate on how this is done?

Comment: Look up "regular maximal subalgebras", also "Borel-de Siebenthal" (https://mathoverflow.net/q/28878/27465). Many related questions have been asked here, but I'd like to see a definitive answer myself.

Comment: It may be through the affine Dynkin diagram, as you mentioned. It is not necessary for the subalgebra to be of equal rank to the algebra, so it is not a contradiction that so(p)⊕so(q) has a lower rank than so(p+q).

As another example, g2⊕f4 is a subalgebra of e8, as the representation theory decomposition follows **248** = (**14**,**1**)⊕(**1**,**52**)⊕(**7**,**26**). Note that g2⊕f4 has rank 6, lower than 8. While it is less clear how to find this through the Dynkin diagram of the affine extension of e8, the 2-dimensional projection to a2⊕e6 provides further clarity on why g2⊕f4 is in e8.